# Regex for escaping forward slashes and back slashes

Tags: regex

I need a regex that can match on forward slashes and back slashes so that I can escape them. However I don't want the regex to match on the following string:

```
\\\\"Hello World\\\\"
```

So for example

```
 / / ////////" \\\\\\\   \\\\"Hello World\\\\"
```

It should match on each slash EXCEPT where there are four slashes followed by a quote with any characters followed by another four quotes with a quote.

Comment: Which programming language are you using ? Why do you need this?

Comment: C# .NET I need to escape slashes before they are sent to elasticsearch for example BP 120/30 I would like it to be escaped 120//30

Comment: "***BP 120/30 I would like it to be escaped 120//30***" you're not escaping anything here.

Comment: @PedroLobito sorry it was a typo, 120\\/30

Answer (score 1, accepted):

> BP 120/30 I would like it to be escaped 120\\/30

```
Regex.Replace(subjectString, "(/{1})", @"\\$1");
```

Backslash example (`BP 120\30`):

```
Regex.Replace(subjectString, @"(\\{1})", @"\\\\$1");
```